# Mule - Failed to route via HTTPS Endpoint

Tags: mule

I have a flow with an HTTPS inbound request/response that accepts a post with XML data (Port 8081).  I do some processing with the data and then want to perform another HTTPS post via 443 to a different URL so that the data gets processed by an external process (PeopleSoft IB).

The problem is that when I try to post to the HTTPS:443 outbound what has come in from HTTPS:8081 inbound, I get the error shown below.

**BUT**, if I have the inbound connector set as HTTP and *not* HTTPS and comment out the https:connector name="httpsConnector" I have setup, everything works perfectly and I can post to the HTTPS/443 endpoint.

I've searched high and low and tried many different things to try to get around this error but all attempts so far have failed.  I know it has something to do with the payload as MuleSoft is balking at it and never routes to the HTTPS endpoint.  I confirmed this by changing the payload to plain text and it was sent successfully.  It also is sent successfully as I noted above, when I come inbound as HTTP to 8081.

I am a MuleSoft neophyte so if this is a simple fix please excuse my ignorance.

**Error Summary**

```
Failed to route event via endpoint:  
DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://corp853.dev.corp.edu:443/PSIGW
/HttpListeningConnector, connector=HttpsConnector { name=httpsConnector lifecycle=start  
this=3a2b2faa numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4 
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true connected=true supportedProtocols=[https] 
serviceOverrides= session.handler=org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler 
message.factory=org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory } , 
name='endpoint.https.corp853.dev.corp.edu.443.PSIGW.HttpListeningConnector', 
mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={exceptionOnMessageError=true, http.method=POST}, 
transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, 
deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, 
endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: 
PostMethod
```

**Catch Error**

```
Could not find a transformer to transform
"SimpleDataType{type=org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod,
mimeType='text/xml'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler,  
mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) 
(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). The current MuleMessage is null! Please 
report this to dev@mule.codehaus.org 
(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: 
PostMethod
```

**Log Details**

```
+ Started app 'checklisttest'                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,623 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=6cca1ad0-2f6e-11e4-89b1-001c42000009
  payload=org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    Content-Type=text/xml
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    Accept=*/*
    Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate
    Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control=no-cache
    Connection=true
    Content-Length=632
    Content-Type=text/xml
    Host=localhost:8082
    Keep-Alive=true
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.https.localhost.8082.checklist.v1
    MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS=/127.0.0.1:56585
    Origin=chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
    Postman-Token=721feb2b-281c-382e-169d-2c2792153944
    User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
    http.context.path=/checklist_v1
    http.context.uri=https://localhost:8082/checklist_v1
    http.headers={Origin=chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop, Keep-Alive=true, Accept=*/*, Connection=true, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36, Host=localhost:8082, Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, Cache-Control=no-cache, Postman-Token=721feb2b-281c-382e-169d-2c2792153944, Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.8, Content-Length=632, Content-Type=text/xml}
    http.method=POST
    http.query.params={}
    http.query.string=
    http.relative.path=
    http.request=/checklist_v1
    http.request.path=/checklist_v1
    http.version=HTTP/1.1
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    LOCAL_CERTIFICATES=[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;@59884baf
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,636 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,642 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,643 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,643 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'httpsConnector.dispatcher.699512478'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,645 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'httpsConnector.dispatcher.699512478'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-08-29 04:20:04,660 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest: Content-Type not set on outgoing request, defaulting to: text/plain
ERROR 2014-08-29 04:20:04,698 [[checklisttest].httpsConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://corp853.dev.corp.edu:443/PSIGW/HttpListeningConnector, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=httpsConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=3a2b2faa
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=
    session.handler=org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler
    message.factory=org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory
}
,  name='endpoint.https.corp853.dev.corp.edu.443.PSIGW.HttpListeningConnector', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={exceptionOnMessageError=true, http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. The server corp853.dev.corp.edu failed to respond (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException)
  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase:1976 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://corp853.dev.corp.edu:443/PSIGW/HttpListeningConnector, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=httpsConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=3a2b2faa
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=
    session.handler=org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler
    message.factory=org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory
}
,  name='endpoint.https.corp853.dev.corp.edu.443.PSIGW.HttpListeningConnector', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={exceptionOnMessageError=true, http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:151 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server corp853.dev.corp.edu failed to respond
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

My project XML is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
<https:connector name="httpsConnector" clientSoTimeout="10000"
    cookieSpec="netscape" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" proxyHostname="localhost"
    receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0"
    serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory" 
        sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
    <https:tls-client path="${corp.folder}/conf/mulekeystore.jks"
        storePassword="pwd" />
    <https:tls-key-store path="${corp.folder}/conf/mulekeystore.jks"
        keyPassword="pwd" storePassword="pwd" />
    <https:tls-server path="${corp.folder}/conf/mulekeystore.jks"
        storePassword="pwd" />
</https:connector>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="corpProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders"
            value="true" />
        <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:custom.properties" />
        <!-- Added to support multiple placeholders -->
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="checklisttestFlow1" doc:name="checklisttestFlow1">
    <https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml"
        connector-ref="httpsConnector" path="checklist_v1" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="corp853.dev.corp.edu" port="443" path="PSIGW/HttpListeningConnector"
        method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1):

For all those curious this issue came down to having a keystore configured with the appropriate certificate for the HTTPS outbound endpoint. This was discovered with the assistance of MuleSoft support.

What was done to figure this out was:

1. Adding log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG  to log4j.properties and then adding this file to src/main/resources (I'm running locally)
2. Removing localhost as proxy from the HTTPS outbound connector

This revealed the following in the trace which showed clearly what the problem was.

```
Root Exception stack trace:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:344)
at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:109)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I did not previously have a keystore associated with the HTTPS outbound connector (I did with the inbound) as one is *not* needed when I come in as HTTP and then go out as HTTPS.  I found though, after much pain, that a keystore *is* required with inbound as HTTPS and outbound as HTTPS.

In this outbound HTTPS keystore I added the certificate for the website (listening connector for PeopleSoft Integration Broker) and all is well.

Comment: When you say "That a keystore is required with inbound as HTTPS and outbound as HTTPS" you acutally meant  "That a keystore is required with inbound as HTTP and outbound as HTTPS" right ? inbound is HTTP not HTTPS

Comment: So how do you configure this keystore?

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen this exact error, but I think I have an idea of what could help. Try adding an object-to-string transformer after the https inbound endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me.  Trying that unfortunately produces the same error.  Note that I have sent this problem to MuleSoft support.  Once I get a resolution I will post it here.